# D3.js (v.4) scatterplot zooming issue

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Using d3.js v4.1.1 I have created the scatterplot with time-scale and zoom by brush functionality.
It works just fine, but I have an issue: while zooming, the area of the plot overlaps with axises. Just like this:

[image: Scatter-plot]

Here is the code for scatterplot creation:

```
var margin = {
    top: 10,
    right: 20,
    bottom: 30,
    left: 50
  },
  width = 510 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 300 - margin.top - margin.bottom,
  idleTimeout, idleDelay = 350;

var x = d3.scaleTime().range([0, width]);
var y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);
var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x);
var yAxis = d3.axisLeft(y);
var div = d3.select(id).append('div').attr('class', 'legend');
var brush = d3.brush().on("end", brushended);
var svg = div
  .append("svg")
  .attr("class", "scatter")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom).append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
var x0 = d3.extent(articlesData, function(d) {
  return moment(d.code).toDate();
});
var y0 = d3.extent(articlesData, function(d) {
  return d.qty;
});
x.domain(x0).nice();
y.domain(y0).nice();
svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "axis axis--x")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(xAxis);
svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "axis axis--y")
  .call(yAxis);
svg.append("g").attr("class", "brush").call(brush).append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

function brushended() {
  var s = d3.event.selection;
  if (!s) {
    if (!idleTimeout)
      return idleTimeout = setTimeout(idled, idleDelay);
    x.domain(x0);
    y.domain(y0);
  } else {
    x.domain([s[0][0], s[1][0]].map(x.invert, x));
    y.domain([s[1][1], s[0][1]].map(y.invert, y));
    svg.select(".brush").call(brush.move, null);
  }
  zoom();
}

function idled() {
  idleTimeout = null;
}

function zoom() {
  var t = svg.transition().duration(750);
  svg.select(".axis--x").transition(t).call(xAxis);
  svg.select(".axis--y").transition(t).call(yAxis);
  svg.selectAll("circle").transition(t)
    .attr("cx", function(d) {
      return x(moment(d.code).toDate());
    })
    .attr("cy", function(d) {
      return y(d.qty);
    });
}
```

Here is the working jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/anka976/4utscejm/1/

Does anybody know what's wrong here?

Comment: You need to define a clipPath. Have a look at Mike Bostock's Block [*Zoomable Area*](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4015254).

Comment: thanks, @altocumulus!  It helped, here is the updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/anka976/4utscejm/5/